# Web Service XML request format from WSDL

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am starting up with web service and I have just faced up a doubt. I have the WSDL file and I want to develop the web service. I have tried out with Axis2 and CXF and I do not know if the problem is conceptual, or technical.

My tutor give me this wsdl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://ws.unit4.com" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" targetNamespace="http://ws.unit4.com">

    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ws.unit4.com">

            <xs:element name="InsertDog">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="param0" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>

            <xs:element name="InsertDogResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>

        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <wsdl:message name="InsertDogRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:InsertDog"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:message name="InsertDogResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:InsertDogResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:portType name="InsertDogPortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="InsertDog">
            <wsdl:input message="ns:InsertDogRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:InsertDog"/>
            <wsdl:output message="ns:InsertDogResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:InsertDogResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name="InsertDogSoap11Binding" type="ns:InsertDogPortType">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="InsertDog">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:InsertDog" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="InsertDogServ">
        <wsdl:port name="InsertDogHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:InsertDogTransSoap11Binding">
            <soap:address location="x.x.x.x"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

And my tutor said me also that this web service has to be able to receive and XML document like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:q0="http://ws.unit4.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
      <NewDog xmlns="http://gfr.com/">
          <name>Kira</name> 
          <owner>John Smith</owner> 
          <contactNumber>123456789</contactNumber>
      </NewDog>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But I receive an error like:

```
...      
<soapenv:Fault>
<faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ns1:Client</faultcode> 
<faultstring>No such operation 'NewDog'</faultstring> 
...
```

I do not know if I am wrong or not, but, shouldn't be the wsdl schema part like this one below to work out with this XML request?

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ws.unit4.com">

    <xs:element name="NewDog">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="owner" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="contactNumber" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="InsertDogResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Thank you very much in advance :) and happy weekend!!

Comment: The WSDL you gave is not complete. Could you post the entire WSDL here? Anyway from what I can see there is no NewDog Operation so if you could post the entire WSDL I would have a look.

Comment: Hi Namphibian. It is already changed. THANKS!

Comment: From the looks of your WSDL, the `NewDog` should be `InsertDog`. What did you generate the request payload with?

Comment: Yes you are right, it should be like that, but the message format does not match with the first wsdl. I had to change the schema and the namespaces to make it working and now workds correctly. Does ever this message format would work with that wsdl? I would say not... thanks for the response